# Chaos Testing Tool for Kubernetes environment - with Java client

Tags: java, docker, testing, kubernetes, automated-tests

I'm looking for a chaos testing tool to run in a Kubernetes environment.

I have a micro-services environment in which every service runs on a separate pod.

I'm looking to cause network connectivity issues, file system errors, services crash, and so on.

I want to do it - and this is the most important part - when the system and each service are in a particular state (pre-conditions).

I researched a few tools Like Litmus and Chaos Mesh.
If I understood correctly, the issue with them is that they are operating from outside of the Kubernetes cluster.
I define a custom resource for each chaos scenario, and whenever I invoke it, the chaos begins without consideration to the current state of the machine.

I'm looking for a tool that can do all this chaos while considering the existing state of the services.
I guess it means it should be done somehow from within the code itself, while having access to all the services and their state.

All my eco-system is written in Java.
So far, what I found is a tool called Toxiproxy, but I'm not sure it can shut down services and bring them up as part of the chaos.

Are you familiar with other tools that can be used for chaos from within the code and have a Java client?

Thanks